# Parsing date using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Example log:

> 05/13/15 17:11:02 hello world

How to parse the given date format using logstash date filter?

Comment: Please could you show what you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now:

```
    date {
      target => '@timestamp'
      match => [ 'mydatefield', 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss' ]
    }
```